# Changing LTspice hotkeys on Mac

Tags: ltspice

Any LTspice Mac user knows that hotkeys are necessary to be efficient. I would like to create my own (for example, D for diode, R for resistor, V for voltage source, etc), but all the directions I find on how to set my own hotkeys are only for the Windows version. What is the procedure for customizing LTspice hotkeys on a Mac?

Comment: Where did you search ? https://www.analog.com/media/en/simulation-models/spice-models/LTspiceShortcutsForMacOSX.pdf?modelType=spice-models

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75:  The question is about **changing** hotkeys, not about what the standard hotkeys are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted the LTspice team. They said that there was not currently a way to change hotkeys on the Mac version, and that even the way to change them on the Windows version was a "hack". They also said that the product is still under development and that they will try to implement it in future versions, but that could take some time.

Answer (score 0):

locate the LTspiceXVII.ini file or equiv in MAC and edit them

Text_Anchor_Marks=A
Place_Ground=G
Place_Resistor=R
Place_Capacitor=C
Place_Inductor=L
Place_Diode=D
Draw_Lines=(none)
Draw_Rectangles=(none)
Draw_Circles=(none)
Draw_Arcs=(none)
Reset_T_0=0 )
Schematic_Grid=Ctrl+G
Rotate=Ctrl+R
Mirror=Ctrl+E
Zoom_Area=Ctrl+Z
Zoom_Back=Ctrl+B
Halt_Simulation=Ctrl+H
Run_Simulation=(none)
Place_BUS_Tap=(none)
Zoom_to_Fit=Space
View_SPICE_Error_Log=Ctrl+L
Place_Voltage_Source=V
[AsyKeyBoardShortCut]
Object_Anchors=O
Place_Pin=P
Delete_Mode=F5
Duplicate_Mode=F6
Move_Mode=F7
Drag_Mode=F8
Undo=F9
Redo=Shift+F9
Place_Comment_Text=T
Draw_Lines=L
Draw_Rectangles=R
Draw_Arcs=A
Draw_Circles=C
Rotate=Ctrl+R
Mirror=Ctrl+E
Attribute_Editor=Ctrl+A
Attribute_Window=Ctrl+W
Zoom_Back=Ctrl+B
Zoom_In=Ctrl+Z
Zoom_to_Fit=Space
Show_Pin_Table=(none)
[RawKeyBoardShortCut]
Zoom_Extents=Ctrl+E
Zoom_Area=Ctrl+Z
Zoom_Back=Ctrl+B
Vertically_Autorange=Ctrl+Y
Toggle_Grid=Ctrl+G
Delete_Mode=F5
Add_Trace=Ctrl+A
Add_Pane=(none)
Undo=F9
Redo=Shift+F9
Run_Simulation=(none)
Halt_Simulation=Ctrl+H
Open_Plot_Settings_File=(none)
Reload_Plot_Settings_File=Space
Label_cursor_position=F4
Place_text_on_the_plot=T
Draw_an_arrow_on_the_plot=(none)
Draw_a_line_on_the_plot=F3
Draw_a_box_on_the_plot=(none)
Draw_a_circle_on_the_plot=(none)
Annotation_Line_Style/Color=(none)
Copy_Plot_Annotations=F6
Move_Plot_Annotations=F7
Drag_Plot_Annotations=F8
Select_Steps=(none)
View_SPICE_Error_Log=Ctrl+L
Redraw_Window=(none)
[NetKeyBoardShortCut]
Goto_Line_Number=Ctrl+G
Run_Simulation=Ctrl+R
Pause_Simulation=(none)
Halt_Simulation=Ctrl+H
Undo=F9
Redo=Shift+F9
View_SPICE_Error_Log=Ctrl+L

Comment: Advice on where to find said file, or what it might be named? I've been looking around and not found it. Very possible I'm not looking in the right place

Comment: I looked & could not find either from extracting the Mac install in 7zip and scanning possible files in every folder.  Try LTspice@linear.com